# where and how do i save the jdk link so that eclipse will open?

Tags: java, eclipse

When I go to open eclipse, it gives me a run time error saying that the path to the JDK is not right.

I have no idea where to save the link so that i can get it to open

Comment: You put the path in the eclipse.ini file, lots of existing answers for this.

Answer (score 1):

First Install Java on your pc: It should create Java Folder in C:\Program Files.

You have to set Classpath like this :

```
Set the CLASSPATH environment variable

    (for **Windows NT/2000/XP**)

1. At the left bottom corner of your computer desktop, choose Start -> Setting -> Control Panel, and double-click System

2. On Microsoft Windows NT, select the Environment tab; on Microsoft Windows 
2000/XP select the Advanced tab and then Environment Variables.

3. For either User variables or System variables, click New and in the popup window, enter Variable name as CLASSPATH (note that all letters should be capital), and the directory where your JDK is installed as the Variable value.

For example:

If your JDK is installed at: C:\jdk1.4.1_06

Put the following line as the value:

C:\jdk1.4.1_06\bin;C:\jdk1.4.1_06\jre\bin;.

The first is where the java compiler 'javac' is, the second is the java run time environment 'java' is, and the final '.' denotes your working directory, so that the compiler and jre will find where your programs are.  To be safe, you may also want to append the above line to then end of your PATH variable. Use ';' as the separator.

Save the variables, test the setting by opening a DOS prompt, type in

echo %CLASSPATH%

If your environment variables are set correctly, you should see your settings.

Or, you can just type in 

javac

java

If your PATH and CLASSPATH is correct, windows should recognize those commands.

You do NOT need to restart your computer when installing Java.

Check whether TextPad and Java SDK work on your computer
    Download HelloWorld.java into your local drive. Be sure that filename is case sensetive in JAVA programming.
    Start TextPad, and open this HelloWorld.java file.
    Click menu "Tools" ---> "Compile Java" to compile java file.
    Click menu "Tools" ---> "Run Java Application" to run this file.

If you see "Hello World" in a DOS PROMPT window, that means there is no problem with your TextPad to compile/run Java program. Congratulations. You can start your java programming now. If you see some errors when run Java program, please click here to get more information.
For a more comprehensive description on how to setup Java environment on Windows machinese, please refer to the Sun document at: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/install-windows.html

For **windows 7**: Follow this link http://www.abodeqa.com/2012/08/11/how-to-set-path/
```

**Then** : Start Compatible eclipse (e.g :64bit eclipse on 64bit os).

In Eclipse, select Windows | Preferences

Click the + in front of Java or double-click Java (after the +)

Click Installed JREs

Under the Name column, double-click jre1.5.0_08.

Click the Add External Jars... button.

In the Jar Selection window, navigate to your workspace folder, and double-click the file cs15-1xx.library.

In the Edit JRE window, click OK

In the Installed JREs window, click OK

Terminate (X) the Welcome window
You can always get it back by selecting Help | Welcome

Terminate (X) the Eclipse window.

**For more Details follow this** : http://blog.ajduke.in/2013/04/28/setting-up-new-java-compiler-and-runtime-in-eclipse-ide/

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the target JRE when launching eclipse by with the -vm command line argument (either through a shortcut or in the eclipse.ini file).

- Command line syntax: `eclipse -vm c:\jre\bin\javaw.exe`
- eclipse.ini file syntax (**use 2 lines**)

> ```
> -vm
> c:/jre/bin/javaw.exe
> ```

You can also copy a given version of the JRE under your eclipse installation directory.

Generally speaking I would **really advise against adding %JAVA_HOME%/bin to your SYSTEM path**. In my experience, this usually leads to many unexpected behaviors. Far better IMHO to set the JAVA_HOME and add its /bin directory to the PATH through scripts/command line/shortcuts/etc. and invoke those when needed.